# How can I undo SetWindowDisplayAffinity method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user32

I have a C# application that prevents screen capturing, but I want to disable "black screen".

Here is my code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern uint SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hWnd, uint dwAffinity);

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this.Handle, WDA_MONITOR);
}
```

In which way I can disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), to exclude a window from capture, pass `WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE` or `WDA_MONITOR` as parameter and to undo (include in capture), pass `WDA_NONE`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hWnd, uint dwAffinity);
const uint WDA_NONE = 0x00000000;
const uint WDA_MONITOR = 0x00000001;
const uint WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE = 0x00000011;

private void includeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this.Handle, WDA_NONE);
}

private void excludeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this.Handle, WDA_MONITOR);
}
```

The following screenshot shows the Window is included in capture:

[image: included]

The following screenshot shows the Window is excluded from capture:

[image: excluded]